# cvCvtColor Crashes while converting from RGB to GRAY

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

Example code:

```
IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage (cvSize(currentImage->width, currentImage->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor (currentImage, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

It crashes on cvCvtColor function. I have tried channel as 3 for cvCreateImage, no luck. Height and width are 640 and 480, depth 8, sizeof(IplImage) is 112 and Image data size in bytes 921600.

OpenCV version 2.3.1 running in raspberry pi.

Comment: It crashes even if I use
`cvCvtColor (currentImage, currentImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);`

Comment: First Get rid of the depreciated C API and please show us the error message. Also make sure the  "currentImage" is a 3 channel mat.

Comment: That gives following error:
`Caught SIGSEGV
#0  0x76c0ab80 in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x76d1f528 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0`

Comment: Trying to use from custom gstreamer plugin which is written in C, so trying the C APIs of opencv.

Comment: I think I have found the issue, seems like this is related to image size, it crashes with large image size. Trying different things. Thanks.